# How to compare library(kknn) results to validation model to see performance of model

Tags: r, knn

I've got a model where I'm trying to predict my 11th column titled R1. My data looks like this:

```
A1    A2     A3     A8 A9 A10 A11 A12 A14   A15     R1
1   1 30.83  0.000  1.250  1   0   1   1 202     0  1
2   0 58.67  4.460  3.040  1   0   6   1  43   560  1
3   0 24.50  0.500  1.500  1   1   0   1 280   824  1
```

And my code looks like this:

```
data <- read.delim("credit_card_data-headers.txt")
m <- dim(data)[1]
#val grabs a random 3rd
val <- sample(1:m, size = round(m/3), replace = FALSE,
              prob = rep(1/m, m))
#data.learn gets assiged 2/3rds of the whole data
data.learn <- data[-val,]
#data.valid gets the left over 1/3rd
data.valid <- data[val,]
#build up the k nearest neighbor predictions for the R1 column
data.kknn <- kknn(R1~., data.learn, data.valid, k=3, distance = 1,
                  kernel = "triangular", scale = TRUE)
```

I think I'm doing the KKNN right, but I have no idea how to compare my results to the data.valid set to see my success/failure percentage. I'm trying to do this:

```
fit <- fitted(data.kknn)
fit
```

But it gives me a this for my 'fit':

```
[1] 0.00000000 0.63903156 0.99028609 0.20950708 0.00000000 0.42680166 0.03538045 1.00000000 0.59672292 1.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000
```

I don't know how to interpret this continuous vector of values. How do I do some type of comparison to see how good my model is? (something like a confusion matrix or percent correct)

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. I just rounded those values and that seemed to work find.